Sorting rows in ascending order by multiple fields in QGIS
Fields:
year field is 2020,2021,2022(integer)
month field is 1~12(integer)
day field is 1~31 (integer)
time field is 0~23(integer)

I've used:
"year" || lpad("month", 3, 0) || lpad("day", 3, 0) || lpad("time", 3, 0)

in the "Configure Attribute Table Sort Order" menu.
And with the field calculator as:
array_find(
    array_agg($id,
        order_by:= "Year"  ||  "Month"  ||  "Day"  ||  "Hour" )
    ,$id)
+1


This question is similar to: Sorting by multiple fields at same time in QGIS?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@VJP, what's wrong with the expression "year" || lpad("month", 3, 0) || lpad("day", 3, 0) || lpad("time", 3, 0)? It should work without issues.

How about actually using a date type?

I was confused bit, I've found it too work fine, THX

Concatenate the columns into a string in the format of '2024-09-23 7' Create a datetime object from string, and sort by it:
to_datetime(format('%1-%2-%3 %4', "year", "month", "day", "hour"),
    format:='yyyy-M-d H')

See:

format
to_datetime
QDate class and
QTime

yyyy means "The year as a four digit number", M "The month as a number without a leading zero", d "The day as a number without a leading zero" and H "The hour without a leading zero"

